# How to Write a Custom Alert Format for Suricata Alerts

Tags: logging

I'm trying to write a (very simple) custom format for a Suricata alert for ingest into a Python application I have written.

In the [documentation](http://fossies.org/linux/suricata/suricata.yaml.in) I've found, it indicates that some fields, like "- http-log:", support a 'customvalue' option.  I'm trying to determine if the "-fast" section, which generates the alerts I'm interested in, supports custom formats as well.

If anyone has ever written a custom alert format for Suricata's fast.log I would be interested to learn how you did it.  Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Suricata does not support custom alert formats for its "-fast" line-based alerts at the time of writing. The [documentation](http://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/suricata-yaml.html?highlight=fast#line-based-alerts-log-fast-log) for Suricata configuration only has a few options (specifying filename and append options) for this type of alert logging. The latest Suricata source (downloadable [here](https://suricata-ids.org/download/)) shows that the output for the -fast logging option is a hard-coded format in the `alert-fastlog.c` file shown below.

[image: alert-fastlog.c]

Given that the Suricata fast alert format was designed to be the same format as the Snort [alert_fast](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/snort-cookbook/0596007914/ch02s23.html) logging option, it may be helpful to leverage an existing Python [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406544/parsing-snort-logs-with-pyparsing) for parsing Snort alerts, and apply a similar approach in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use lua scripts to generate your own output formats. There is an example in the source that implements a fast-log like output here: https://github.com/inliniac/suricata/blob/master/lua/fast.lua

Documentation of the Lua options in Suricata can be found here: http://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/output/lua-output.html